# Like .htaccess file can I add .properties file in Apache server configuration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I know it a silly question but last night when I was working with my website's .properties file, I discovered this idea. I am using PHP script for my website where I have stored all my site properties values like image path, secure path.. etc in **website.properties** file. But I need to include this .properties file in each and every webpages to access the values in it.

My question is, like .htaccess file, can I add this .propeties file into server configuration? Is there any option available to sync this file with server configuration? Is Apache allowing us to do? In this case I don't need to add this file in every pages.

Answer (score 0):

Look to the side of enviromental variables in Apache and PHP:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I said, like .htaccess file is not a php file, you can not set php tag on that, same for .properties file, currently the server read this file as text format and I have declared a JS object on that and values are in json format. I donot want to include this file on the webpage, but I can access the page values globally (platform independent).

Comment: You can add some library to httpd.conf, which will parse that JSON object and will load as env variable to apache, I can't see simpler solution at this moment.

Comment: Yes, that's may be a path. Let me try this one. Thanks